# Задание из ЕГЭ по информатике с помощью JS

Tags: javascript

30го числа ЕГЭ, время на подготовку совсем нету, чисто случайно попалась программа, котоая решает задачи подобного плана:

> У исполнителя Утроитель две команды,
> которым присвоены номера:
> 1. прибавь 2,
> 2. умножь на 3.
> Сколько существует программ,
> которые число 1 преобразуют в число 55?

Но она на Win XP, а мне бы на айподе её использовать. Конечно задачку то я решить могу, но там можно ошибиться в вычислениях + товарищ нифига не смыслит в этом, тоже хотелось бы и ему помочь. Ну и я загорелся написать программу под айпод, т.к. знаниями Objective C не располагаю, решил просто на JS сделать страничку в инете, на которой можно будет это решать. Но вот начал думать, что-то даже и не знаю, как сделать.

Алгоритм то такой: постипенно выполнять эту задачу для чисел меньше 55, т.е. сначала для 2, потом для 3 и т.д. Формула такая: `R(n) = R(n-2) + R(n/3)` это для данной задачи. `R(n)` - это кол-во программ, n это число в которое преобразовать. Если n не делется на 3, то `R(n/3)` приравнивать к 0. И получается нам нужно найти только `R(2)`,`R(3)` своим умом и логикой, `R(2)=0` (т.к. таких программ не существует), `R(3) = 2` (можно умножить 1 на 3 или прибавить 2 к 1). А дальше уже подставляем всё в первую формулу: `R(4) = R(4-2) + R(4/3)` 4/3 не делится, поэтому равно 0, следовательно `R(4) = R(2) = 0`. И так далее, до 55. Вот такой алгоритм впринципе я представляю как организовать. Можно создать массив с этими занчениями просто и всё и также работать, только будет не `R(2)`, в `R[2]`. Но я не знаю как вычислить первые `R(2)`,`R(3)` с помощью JS.

Помогите пожалуйста. Ведь программы раздые бывают, может быть из числа 8 в число 27, с разными операциями исполнителя(например будут уже умножить на 2 и прибавить 3). И вопрос именно как определить первые элементы массива, чтобы от них уже строить остальные по формуле `R(n) = R(X) + R(X)`

**UPD:
Вот и программа, написал благодаря алгоритму IVsevolod:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">

<title>Б13</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function Schet(n)
{
  var f = document.getElementById('forma');
  var result = 0;
  var num = Number(f.num2.value);

  if(f.can1.value=='plus')
  var n1 = n + Number(f.k1.value);
  else if(f.can1.value=='mnozh')
  var n1 = n * f.k1.value;
  else if(f.can1.value=='sqr')
  var n1 = n * n;
  if(f.can1.value!=""){
  if (n1 == num) result++; 
  if (n1 < num) result += Schet(n1);
  }

  if(f.can2.value=='plus')
  var n2 = n + Number(f.k2.value);
  else if(f.can2.value=='mnozh')
  var n2 = n * f.k2.value;
  else if(f.can2.value=='sqr')
  var n2 = n * n;
  if(f.can2.value!=""){
  if (n2 == num) result++; 
  if (n2 < num) result += Schet(n2);
  }

  if(f.can3.value=='plus')
  var n3 = n + Number(f.k3.value);
  else if(f.can3.value=='mnozh')
  var n3 = n * f.k3.value;
  else if(f.can3.value=='sqr')
  var n3 = n * n;
  if(f.can3.value!=""){
  if (n3 == num) result++; 
  if (n3 < num) result += Schet(n3);
  }

  return result;   
}
function ECHO(msg){
document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = '<b>Ответ:</b> '+msg;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id=forma>
<b>Исполнитель умеет выполнять следующие команды:</b><br/>
<select name=can1><option value=""> </option><option selected value='plus'>Прибавь</option><option value='mnozh'>Умнож на</option><option value='sqr'>Возведи в квадрат</option></select> 
<input name=k1 type=text value="2" size=5><br/><br/>
<select name=can2><option value=""> </option><option value='plus'>Прибавь</option><option selected value='mnozh'>Умнож на</option><option value='sqr'>Возведи в квадрат</option></select> 
<input name=k2 type=text value="3" size=5><br/><br/>
<select name=can3><option selected value=""> </option><option value='plus'>Прибавь</option><option value='mnozh'>Умнож на</option><option value='sqr'>Возведи в квадрат</option></select>
 <input name=k3 type=text value="0" size=5><br/><br/>
<b>Сколько есть программ, которые преобразуют</b><br/>
число <input name=num1 type=text value="1" size=5> в число <input name=num2 type=text value="55" size=5> <br/>
<button OnClick="ECHO(Schet(Number(document.getElementById('forma').num1.value)));return false;">Решить!</button>
<div id=answer></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ну и формулировочки на ЕГЭ... Понял из текста процентов 20 :)

Comment: У исполнителя Утроитель две команды,
которым присвоены номера:
     1. прибавь 2,
     2. умножь на 3.

> Но я не знаю как вычислить первые R(2),R(3) с помощью JS.

Я правильно понял, что вы не знаете сколькими способами прибавлением числа 2 и умножением на 3 получить числа... 2 и 3?

Comment: Nofate, я то знаю, я не знаю как научить программу узнавать это, ведь все данные динамичны, всё изменяемо.
Zhukov Roman, да, жуть. 4 года назад было намного проще, я брату помогал готовится.

Comment: 2 и 3 для случая с умножением/сложением на 2 и 3 являются точкой отсчета и выполняются в одну операцию.

Если у вас в общем виде есть 

* умножение на a
* прибавление b

то R(a) = R(b) = 1 и никак иначе

Comment: какой то страшный код, надеюсь все таки ваш код работает всегда правильно :)

Comment: проверил на 10 разных заданиях - всё работает)))

Comment: Автор, я тоже сдаю в этом году егэ. Что вы укажите "компилятором" для своего кода? Движок браузера(Gecko, Chromium, Monkey) что ли? Вобщем я бы взял что-нибудь иное.

Comment: Просто заливаю на свой сервак эту страничку, будучи дома захожу на неё с айпода, отключаю интернет, она сохраняется открытой в браузере. JS Safari отлично поддерживает. Если есть возможности, конечно лучше написать приложение под iOS. Но на сколько я знаю, там нужно лицензию покупать)_

Comment: > Что вы укажите "компилятором" для своего кода? Движок браузера(Gecko, Chromium, Monkey) что ли? Вобщем я бы взял что-нибудь иное.

@moron, Есть же node.js (а когда-нибудь еще и [Nashorn](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nashorn/) будет). Выполняйте на здоровье из командной строки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хм. как я понял число 55 может меняться?

я бы сделал **рекурсивно**, что-то типо этого (напишу на псевдо языке):

```
функция Считаем(число)
{
  результат = 0;
  число1 = число + 2;
  число2 = число * 3;
  если (число1 == 55) то результат ++; 
  иначе если (число1 < 55) nj результат += Считаем(число1);

  если (число2 == 55) то результат ++; 
  иначе если (число2 < 55) nj результат += Считаем(число2); 
  вернуть реузльтат;    
}

выводим Считаем(1);
```

Синтаксис JS достаточно прост. На html страничку можно прикрутить пару формочек, и действие прикрутить к кнопке.

надеюсь помог, и вопрос понял правильно :)

Comment: ну да, мне главное алгоритм, я JS и HTML знаю. Попробую вашу программу, но мне кажется она некоторые варианты пропускает, ну щас в JS перепишу и попробую, спасибо большое))

Comment: Почему-то получается 1, должно 32. Щас попробую разобраться, но тяжело с рекурсией разбираться.

Comment: @mctrane не забудьте показать решение :)

Comment: @lampa я щас программку заинтерфейсю и выложу исходник)

Comment: @mctrane, пожалуйста ) был рад помочь :)

Answer (score 1):

**Оттранслировал псевдокод из ответа IVsevolod** на Java (с некоторыми вольностями) и добавил вывод получившихся программ для этой виртуальной машины.

```
public class main {
    static int printCounter = 1;

    static int recurse(int arg, StringBuilder b){
        return check(arg+2, new StringBuilder(b).append("+"))
             + check(arg*3, b.append("*"));
    }


    static int check(int arg, StringBuilder b){
        final int checkResult = 55;

        if (arg == checkResult){
            System.out.print(printCounter++);
            System.out.print("\t");
            System.out.println(b);
            return 1;
        }

        if (arg < checkResult)
            return recurse(arg, b);

        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg){
        System.out.println(check(1, new StringBuilder()));
    }
}
```

Может, кому-то будет интересно побаловаться. :)